# Debounce job name - job name issue

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Using Polymer 1.0...

The debounce method expects the job name to be some kind of object. I get `Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined`.

From [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-debounce), the job name is a string. I thought the job name was just to reference the debounce object later, but I guess I am wrong.

What am I doing wrong here? Note, this is outside a custom element so that is why I am using `Polymer.Base`

```
function scrollSnap() {
  Polymer.Base.debounce('foo', ()=> {
    if (app.selected === 'portfolio') {
      if (panel.scroller.scrollTop > 75 && panel.scroller.scrollTop < 200) {
        panel.scroller.scrollTop = 400;
      } else if  (panel.scroller.scrollTop > 350 && panel.scroller.scrollTop < 400) {
        panel.scroller.scrollTop = 0;
      }
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the internal debouncer map is not initialized, so when Polymer tries to do a debouncer-name lookup, it dereferences an uninitialized/undefined array.

Since this debouncer call is being used outside a Polymer element, you'd have to manually call the setup function that would've normally been done in the element's initialization (i.e., [`_setupDebouncers()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-_setupDebouncers)):

```
Polymer.Base._setupDebouncers();

for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
  Polymer.Base.debounce('foo', () => console.log('debounced'), 1000);
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/WdPvrr?editors=1011)